# is there a way to convert h2oframe to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, h2o

I am able to convert dataframe to h2oframe but how can I convert back to a dataframe? If this is possible not can I convert it to a python list?

```py
import pandas as pd
import h2o
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [2838, 3222, 4576, 5665, 5998], '2': [1123, 3228, 3587, 5678, 6431]})
data = h2o.H2OFrame(df)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Convert h2o frame to List

```
data_as_list = h2o.as_list(data, use_pandas=False)
```

Convert h2o frame to pandas DataFrame. (Default `use_pandas=True`)

```
data_as_df = h2o.as_list(data)
```

Answer (score 25):

There is an H2OFrame method called [`as_data_frame()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html#h2o.frame.H2OFrame.as_data_frame) but `h2o.as_list()` also works.

```
data_as_df = data.as_data_frame()
```